# Extracting OSM railways using ogr2ogr

Tags: openstreetmap, ogr2ogr

Similar to the [question on how to extract highways from osm data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/372386/converting-osm-pbf-to-shp-format-using-ogr2ogr-to-extract-major-highways) I posted before, I now have a new one: I want to extract all features tagged with railway=rail from an osm.pbf file using ogr2ogr. In contrary to the highway key, which is a header in the attribute table, the railway is not. I tried to change this by editing the osmconf.ini file, but I always get the error "ERROR 1: "railway" not recognised as an available field."

```
ogr2ogr -where "railway='rail'" CA-rails.shp central-america-latest.osm.pbf lines
```

Even though, the relevant line in the [lines] part of osmconf.ini was changed.

```
# keys to report as OGR fields
attributes=railway
```

So, the question arises here for me: Did I still not find the correct *osmconf.ini* file, and if so, where is the related file for OSGeo4W saved. Currently, I only find *osmconf.ini* files installed for R.

Otherwise, how can I extract the railway key which is saved under "other_tags" using the command line?

The line I used so far was:

```
ogr2ogr -where "other_tags='railway=rail'" CA-rails.shp central-america-latest.osm.pbf lines
```

Comment: You do not need to guess where the osmcong.ini file is https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/osm.html. As documented, by default it is in the gdal_data directory (check the value of the environment variable) and you can set it explicitly by adding an open option into your command `-oo CONFIG_FILE=filename`